# Generalized concept of subgraph (input/output graphs)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

The usual definition of a vertex-induced subgraph goes like [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-InducedSubgraph.html):

> A vertex-induced subgraph<sub>1</sub> is a subset of the vertices of a graph $G$ 
>   together with any edges *with both endpoints* in this subset.

For itself a subgraph is just a graph which can be embedded into some other graphs which it is a subgraph of.

I wonder if the following weaker (and more general) definition of a subgraph has been investigated before (and been found fruitful):

> A vertex-induced subgraph<sub>2</sub> is a subset of the vertices of a graph $G$ 
>   together with any edges *with at least one endpoint* in this subset.

In the case of directed graphs, this definition gives rise to interesting features a subgraph<sub>2</sub> $G_2$ can have, but not a a subgraph<sub>1</sub>. These features have to do with the existence of input and output nodes:

- $i$ is an input node of $G_2$ when there is an edge $(n,i)$ in $G_2$ with node $n$ *not* in $G_2$
- $o$ is an output node of $G_2$ when there is an edge $(o,n)$ in $G_2$ with node $n$ *not* in $G_2$.

An interesting feature might be being a source/sink, i.e. not containing an input/output node.

Of course, a subgraph<sub>2</sub> is *not* a graph according to the standard definition of a graph. But it would be equivalent to an "input/output graph" which can be defined as a graph together with two functions $in$ and $out$ assigning to each vertex a number of (virtual) input and output edges.

Once again my question:

> Has the above definition of subgraphs<sub>2</sub> been investigated
>   before?
>
> Alternatively: Has the above
>   definition of input/output graphs been investigated before?

If so, under which name?

Comment: Not an answer if your question is contrued strictly, yet the following two things are tagentially relevant: (1) it is very usual to consider *boundaries* of vertex sets, in the sense of sets of edges with *exactly* one end in the given vertex set, and of course you can cobble together a "definition" from this concept of 'boundary' and the usual 'ordinary subgraph'. (2) when working with e.g. [string diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_diagram) and [operads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory), a concept of **half-edges** exists. I have not seen your idea addressed as such.

Comment: A related definition which *is* a graph, and a problem which is not completely trivial involving that definition". * Define a "1-indirect vertex induced subgraph of graph $G = (V,E)$ induced by $U\subset V$ to have edge-set $F$ of exactly those  edges with at least one vertex in $U$, and vertex set $W$ consisting of those vertices touched by a member of $F$. * The nontrivial problem is:  Find a graph $G$ and subset $U$ of its vertices such that the 1-indirect vertex-induced subgraph of $G$ by $U$ has greater chromatic number than that of the vertex-induced subgraph of $G$  by $U$.